# browser window to stay on top like the "showModelessDialog" method

Tags: javascript, browser

I would like to have a browser window stay on top of other windows similar to the "showModeLessDialog()" method. What I dont like about the "showModeLessDialog()" method is that once the user moves to another page the modeless dialog box disappears.

To get around the closing of the browser window by just opening the browser window through window.open() but the one feature im lacking that I really want is the stay on top featured.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that? The showModeLessDialog is doing it...

Also, Im well aware of various opinions on the subject of forcing windows to stay on top so no need to remind me. I have a good reason for this I assure you. :-)

Comment: I really doubt you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using javascript for popup window,

http://javascript-array.com/scripts/window_open/

you can set these parameters `top=20,left=20`